# How can i accomplish a rotation-transition between 1° and 359° in HTML/CSS with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm reading rotation data from a sensor and sending it to a webpage where i have a 2D-Model, which rotates according to the data.
I've added a css-transition to smooth out the otherwise shaky movement.

The problem is that if the rotation data goes from e.g. 1° rotation to 359° the transition makes the object rotate one round the opposite way to achieve 359° instead of taking the shortest way.
How can i change that?

```js
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('object'),
    deg = 359;
  div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('object'),
    deg = 1;
  div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
#object {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Go to 359&#176;</button>
<button id="button2">Go to 1&#176;</button>
<br/>
<div id="object">UP</div>
```

Comment: what did you expect ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif of course that is what i expect, i'm looking for a solution to change that

Comment: to change what ? you want it to go the shortest path in all the cases ?

Comment: exactly............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotating to -1 will get you there.

```js
document.getElementById('button1').onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('object'),
    deg = -1;
  div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
document.getElementById('button2').onclick = function() {
  var div = document.getElementById('object'),
    deg = 1;
  div.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.mozTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.msTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.oTransform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
  div.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + 'deg)';
}
```

```css
#object {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 30px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1">Go to 359&#176;</button>
<button id="button2">Go to 1&#176;</button>
<br/>
<div id="object">UP</div>
```

So just use some smart calculations to know if you should pass a possitive or negative number...

Comment: yes but what about a generic solution ? i guess the OP is looking for this  or maybe am wasting my brain :p

Comment: @TemaniAfif at a first thought, current positive rotation + target rotation - 360 should provide if the shortest route is clockwise (positive result) or counter-clockwise (negative result). Then is just a matter of passing the positive value to the transform rotate if we want clockwise rotation, or the negative equivalent (for instance, 350 = -10) if we want counter-clockwise rotation

Comment: yes this is what i was going to elaborate as i had a similar case before ... but when i saw your answer i said maybe this is it, he only needed this two values

Comment: @TemaniAfif also if result is zero should compare initial (positive) value and target (positive) value, if the initial is greater (e.g. 350 to 10) rotate CW to the positive, if the target is greater (e.g. 10 to 350) rotate CCW to the negative. It's a pretty entangled thing, so if you can elaborate, please do.  I'm getting dizzy just thinking about it :p

Comment: main issue is that getting current `transform:rotate` value is not easy at all, as using `getPropertyValue("transform")` won't return a `rotate(90deg)`, but a complex `matrix` declaration
https://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/

Comment: scratch all of that. Rotating from  350 to 10 rotates CCW...This is getting challenging

Comment: yes, not easy a lot of cases to consider :) and am not able to find what i did previously :/ so if the OP is not satisfied with your answer i will then create a complete one ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif yup I'm pretty sure I did this a long time ago, in a galaxy far, far away.. but can't seem to find it either. It seems in some cases we should also transform the initial value (i.e. changing from a negative to a positive equivalent or vice-versa) **without** the transition, then apply the new value with the transition.

Comment: @TemaniAfif contrary to what I would have expected (and to MDN definition...), it seems going for a 1 to 180 and 0 to -179 approach, will cause the element to rotate in the proper direction, whether we're going from a negative to negative, negative to positive, positive to positive, or positive to negative.  With the noticeable exception being if the total degrees are more than 180º, then it's getting the wrong way around. 
https://codepen.io/facundocorradini/pen/oqXvex

Comment: yes but i expected this behavior, the direction is always ok ... but the challenge is that we have to change it when it come to a visually long path ... so am not surprised with this .. are you ? what did you expect ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif from MDN: "The amount of rotation created by rotate() is specified by an <angle>. If positive, the movement will be clockwise; if negative, it will be counter-clockwise"... So I expected to use a negative whenever wanted to go CCW (even when going from 50 to 40 deg), and a positive whenever I want to go CW (even from -30 to -20). Guess I misinterpreted what "movement" meant there, it had nothing to do with  the transition

Comment: It seems it's much simple than that, just checking the difference between initial and final value, then just going with the transform if less than 180, and applying the opposite sign equivalent without transition **then** the proper transform with transition if greater.

Comment: ah ok, you need to refer to the difference, that's why you got confused. If the  difference is positive or negative .. by the way since the initial value is 0, the new value will decide, so negative will give negative difference and same positive

Comment: and yes that's it ;) if the difference is between -180 and 180 we keep the original one and if greater that 180 and lower that -180 we do our stuff